# What request path is location = /bar supposed to match in Nginx?

Tags: nginx, configuration, location, httprequest

What request path is location = /bar supposed to match in Nginx?

#### What works fine: `location /bar`

Here is my nginx configuration, host file configuration, and my HTML files.

```
# cat /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/foo
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name foo;

    root /tmp/;

    location /bar/ {
        alias /var/www/foo/;
    }
}

# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost foo
127.0.1.1       debian


# cat /tmp/index.html
Hi! I am Tmp!

# cat /var/www/foo/index.html
<p>Hi! I am Index!</p>

# cat /var/www/foo/max.html
<p>Hi! I am Max!</p>
```

HTTP requests to the root, /bar/, and /bar/max.html produce the expected
output:

```
# systemctl restart nginx && curl http://foo/
Hi! I am Tmp!

# systemctl restart nginx && curl http://foo/bar/
<p>Hi! I am Index!</p>

# systemctl restart nginx && curl http://foo/bar/max.html
<p>Hi! I am Max!</p>
```

#### What does not work fine: `location = /bar`

Now I edit the configuration to replace `location /bar` with `location = /bar`:

```
# cat /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/foo
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name foo;

    root /tmp/;

    location = /bar/ {
        alias /var/www/foo/;
    }
}

# systemctl restart nginx && curl http://foo/
Hi! I am Tmp!
```

These HTTP requests no longer work:

```
# systemctl restart nginx && curl http://foo/bar/
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.10.3</center>
</body>
</html>

# tail -n 1 /var/log/nginx/error.log
2018/05/25 00:07:50 [error] 29157#29157: *1 open() "/tmp/bar/index.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: foo, request: "GET /bar/ HTTP/1.1", host: "foo"

# systemctl restart nginx && curl http://foo/bar
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.10.3</center>
</body>
</html>

# tail -n 1 /var/log/nginx/error.log
2018/05/25 00:08:49 [error] 29203#29203: *1 open() "/tmp/bar" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: foo, request: "GET /bar HTTP/1.1", host: "foo"

# systemctl restart nginx && curl http://foo/bar/max.html
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.10.3</center>
</body>
</html>

# tail -n 1 /var/log/nginx/error.log
2018/05/25 00:10:10 [error] 29265#29265: *1 open() "/tmp/bar/max.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: foo, request: "GET /bar/max.html HTTP/1.1", host: "foo"
```

It appears that the GET requests for either `/bar` or `/bar/` match the `location = /bar/` directive? I thought these requests should have worked with this directive because http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location mentions:

> Also, using the “=” modifier it is possible to define an exact match of URI and location. If an exact match is found, the search terminates.

But as explained in my example, it does not seem to work? What kind of request would match the `location = /bar` directive then?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The URI `/bar/` relies on the `index` directive to *internally* rewrite the URI to `/bar/index.html`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html#index) for details.

The exact match `location` syntax will **only** match the original URI, and **not** the rewritten URI.

`nginx` will process the rewritten URI using the default `location` (which in your configuration, is the `server` context). So, the URI `/bar/index.html` will be searched for at `/tmp/bar/index.html`, and not found.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I replaced `location = /bar/` with `location = /bar/index.html` but now `curl http://foo/bar/` leads to `HTTP 404` and `curl http://foo/bar/index.html` leads to `HTTP 301` redirect to ` http://foo/bar/index.html/`. Can you help me understand what is going on here?

Comment: I suspect you need to change `alias` to `alias /var/www/foo/index.html;` otherwise you have aliased `/bar/index.html` to a directory - and hence the 301 redirection.

Comment: You are right. I changed the `alias` as you said and now `curl http://foo/bar/index.html` does return `HTTP 200`.